# trouble when shutdown or restart in windows xp getting a black screen asking to try and start windows normally or safe mode than it runs a chk disk

Tags: windows-xp

I recently reinstalled windows xp on my dell latitude d410 laptop, everything works fine as long as I don't shut down, when I do, I get a black screen with a list of choices, it gives me the option of trying to start windows normally or different safe modes, than a blue screen comes up and runs a check disk, it even ask me to pick a restore point the last time, which I did, I'm afraid to turn the computer off or restart it, what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Many things you can do.  You can run through chkdsk completely. You can do a windows xp repair installation http://michaelstevenstech.com/XPrepairinstall.htm  (not repair from recovery console, but repair installation) and see if that runs ok.   You can install windows on another hard drive and then copy data across.

I suggest you back data up then you should not be afraid. You can still back it up. e.g. connect to external usb.